# Being a solo Junior Developer. Any advice?

Tags: career-development, software-development

I've been left alone (for my stack - native iOS) as a junior mobile developer in the Squad.

Less than 5 months of programming experience in my life.

I have to continue the development of an ongoing feature (payment) to a huge mobile financial app. There is a monolith, and “my” feature module that already started.

There is integration with new squads module, auth for my new features, clean code (VIP), 100% accessibility goal, QA relation, testing versions, pipelines, testing for network layer, git and back-end stuffs to call, and how knows more… and it starts next Monday.

That is it. No cry, It has to be done. So…it will happen

Any tips to me? How to deal with all, and be able to give fair/honest dates to P.O without even understand all?

Edit. I will come back and have an update how it was, after one/two Sprints, as an update/help to someone living in that sad swamp from Never Ending Story like I do...

Comment: Good luck! Having to estimate projects when  you have no idea how long it'll take happens frequently, just be honest with your PO and if they're insisting double the time you have in your head and remindd them often that you need mentoring. It's not your fault if they make poor choices so just take it as an opportunity to grow.

Comment: Don't make big estimates. They are never accurate. Embrace the [Cone of Uncertainty](http://www.agilenutshell.com/cone_of_uncertainty) and use short [sprints](https://www.atlassian.com/agile/scrum/sprints) to measure your progress.

Comment: I really appreciate the advices. I'll take a look in the info. In fact, I really did not sleep well in the last days and start making some impact into my personal life...

Comment: @Asimov_1984 no job is worth sacrificing your life for unless you have absolutely no other option. You're being thrown to the wolves and your body recognizes this which is why you're struggling.

Comment: It's not about estimates so not an answer, but communicate clearly that the fact you was left alone will *not* make you to work overtime etc. Also, if you are a sole dev, you are no longer junior, your responsibility just increased and non-financial benefits (guidance you are not getting) decreased, and it should be reflected with a raise and title update.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, junior developers should be mentored by senior developers or team leads. No responsible team leads or managers would leave a junior developer working alone without some forms of mentoring, guidance, or supervision.

If you give the PO incorrect estimates, and you miss the deadline to deliver the software, that will look bad on your performance review by the end of the year.

Here are my suggestions:

1. **Be honest with the PO:**

   You should be honest and tell the PO that you don't understand some of
   the requirements or tasks, and can't give the PO the estimated time for any requirements or tasks
   that you don't understand yet. Tell the PO that you will need more
   time to study the requirements.
2. **Study the requirements carefully:**

   Next, you study the requirements, and ask the PO to clarify anything
   that is not clear to you. Make sure you understand the scope of each task such as what and how each task should be implemented.
3. **Break the requirements into small tasks:**

   Then, as other answers suggest, you can break down the requirements
   into small tasks that you understand, and can be implemented and
   delivered within a sprint or a small iteration.
4. **Consult manager/team lead/senior developers**:

   For the first few sprints or iterations, maybe, you can also ask the manager, team lead or senior developers for help to double-check your estimates, and make sure that the estimates are reasonable/accurate. They should provide you with a reasonable amount of mentoring and guidance, and should not ignore or leave you alone.
5. **Finally, give the estimates to the PO**.

   At this stage, you should be reasonably confident with the
   estimates, and ready to give them to the PO.

Of course, it is better if you only give the estimate for one sprint or iteration at a time. This way, you can learn from the past sprint/iteration, and give more accurate estimates for the next sprint/iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable words. I will pay attention to all your tips and try make use it on working days to survive.

Comment: @Asimov_1984 I'd add that if at point 5 you are still not sure, add a generous amount of time to that estimate and make very, very clear that it is very rough estimate. If your PO objects, remind them you was employed to be a junior dev and you are still adjusting to the position of a lone, one-person-team dev.

Answer (score 3):

> be able to give fair/honest dates to P.O without even understand all?

You can't give anything except vague approximations if you don't even understand your tasks in detail. So don't try.

Give estimates on portions of the work instead. eg, XYZ feature will be ready next week for testing etc,.

Break the work down into manageable portions and do your estimates with them, anything you're unsure about, ask for clarification until you grasp it.

Answer (score 2):

For making initial estimates, it's useful to think of the "[cone of uncertainty](http://www.agilenutshell.com/cone_of_uncertainty)" which essentially states that the further you get in a process, the more likely you'll be able to give good estimates. Right now with these high level requirements you have absolutely no way to gauge how long things are going to take. Some items you might think will take 3 months and they take a week, others you might think will take a day and they'll take 6 months. So right now, you should be honest with the PO and also start working on requirements.

I do a lot of ADA work with a top 50 traffic website. 100% compliance with WCAG is a noble goal, but my entire job is working on new ADA problems as they crop up, and that has been my job for a year since I was hired, and was my team's job for 2 years before that. We still aren't at 100% compliance. Obviously, I work on a large website with a ton of pages and modules, but regardless, it's not feasible for someone with little experience to build out a site perfectly accessible, let alone while working on doing everything else. Because I work with ADA, that's my perspective, but I'm sure a backend person or devops person would say the same thing about their work in relation to this project.

If they plan to have a solo junior dev do all this work alone, the project will fail. It takes years of effort to master each effort within the scope of this project, so unless they're fine with your CI/CD pipeline being a bitbucket deployment, your QA process being an eye check after your code is deployed, and your ADA testing being fully reliant on an extension like "siteImprove" without JAWS/IOS Voiceover/etc testing, then they can have an end result that is less impressive than they want, doesn't pair nicely with existing systems and could be impossible to maintain because a junior dev wrote all the code for it. Regardless, I think it'd take multiple years for a junior dev to accomplish all of that, and not the yearish estimate they'd probably be hoping for.

Sorry for being so pessimistic, but I'm worried on your behalf that you'll constantly feel like you're letting people down because you don't know how to do something. I want you to know it's not your fault and that they saddled you with completely unrealistic expectations from the get-go.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line:  **NEVER** be a solo junior developer.

At 5 months of experience, not only do you not know what you're doing, but you don't know how to know what you're doing.  You don't know about clean coding standards, modularization, language and technology best practices, unit and integration testing, productionization and deployment, and so on; there are many pieces that go into building an application, and someone with 5 months experience probably does not have expertise in all those fields to be trustworthy to work solo.

The problem is that, as a solo developer, you don't have mentorship to learn these things,  Sure, you can go on SO or search on Google and read articles, but that only goes so far.  You need to feedback loop of a code review procedure, sprint planning and retrospectives, and so on, in order to determine what works and doesn't work from people more senior/experienced than you are.  Without that, you are likely to learn bad habits, antipatterns, gloss over useful tools or practices that are industry-standard but you don't know about, and so on.  You'll end up torpedoing your career by working for years building up bad habits that future companies won't want to put the effort into having you un-learn and you'll be passed over for positions later on.  Put simply, if you were a hiring manager, would you rather hire someone brand new fresh, or hire someone with experience, except their experience is all wrong and you have to make them un-learn everything they know?  In some cases, having a person who knows nothing is better than having a person who knows all the wrong things, and that's the position you're putting yourself in.

Don't say this to management, though, that will make you look very bad.  Here's what you say to management:

> This is a very big project, and I don't have a lot of experience on my resume, as you know.  I can take up this project and try to accomplish it, but based on my experience level, I have a lot to learn, a lot of research to do, and so on.  Given that I am doing this all on my own, it will take me a long time to get up to speed to build this in a way that will be to your expectations.  I encourage you to hire a senior developer to help me build this and mentor me in good skills and development, which will help the project be done faster and to expectations.

This is how you make them care: "If you don't hire someone to mentor me, the product will be shit"; nobody wants a shitty product.  Then the ball is in their court.  One of two things will happen:

1. They will hire someone to help you.  In this case, it could be good for you, or it could be bad for you.  If they hire someone more competent than you, they may fire you.  This would be unfortunate.  Ideally they will hire someone else and also keep you on so you can learn from that person.  Nobody likes working on a huge project solo, so if they fire you then that person will probably end up quitting as well, so the company will be in big trouble  (plus there's the Bus Factor consideration which means they'll want a team of more-than-one anyway).  It's likely they'll keep you, in which case you'll get the mentorship you want.
2. They won't hire someone.  In which case, in my opinion, you're torpedoing your career by remaining a this company long-term.  As I said, you don't want to learn bad habits, and at this point in your career you should seek mentorship.  If your company is in such dire financial straits that adding a single developer headcount to a critical and understaffed project will break their bank, the company is probably at risk anyway, and as much as companies don't like employees who are flight risks, employees shouldn't work at companies who are financially insolvent.  You should find another job at a company that can afford to have you.  I speak as someone who worked at two companies (back to back, in fact) which had serious financial solvency issues, and it was not fun in either case.  Don't do that, it's bad.